# JFETs question about pinch-off voltage

Tags: jfet

Can the pinch-off voltage be equal to zero?

In my opinion no, because the JEFT would be off all the time, isn't it?

Comment: I suggest that you **study** how a JFET works. The JFET is a "pinch off device. It **needs** a \$V_{gs}\$ < 0 to create the depletion layer that will "pinch the current off". That **cannot happen** when \$V_{gs}\$ = 0. Devices that are **off** when their \$V_{gs}\$ = 0 do exist: N_channel MOSFETs.

Answer (score 0):

A JFET is unlikely to have a pinch-off voltage of zero as there would only be a couple of hundred millivolts before the gate to channel diode would start conducting.

However MOSFETs with zero voltage threshold are available.

[N-CHANNEL ZERO THRESHOLD MOSFET](https://www.aldinc.com/pdf/ALD110800.pdf)